# I want to extract a string from a string, whose values will change

Tags: python

I have an output which will vary in length and values, and I wish to extract a value from it.

This is my output:

```
'+CPBR: 1,"111",129,"0|2|XX"^M'
```

In this case, I want to extract the "XX",

However, I will want to extract the "9X" if the value is:

```
'+CPBR: 1,"111",129,"01|2|9X"^M'
```

Does anybody know a good way to do this?

Comment: Are your strings really that consistent in their formatting?  If so:  `s[-5:-3]` will do it.  If not, please explain more about the format of the output.

Comment: They are not always that consistent, as you can see that would work for the first output, but not the second. instead of XX, it may read in XXXXX. The only consistencies are that it is after the second | and ends in "

Comment: That's the exact piece of information that is vital to solving this problem :).  Otherwise, we're just guessing at what algorithm should be used to parse the string.

Comment: oops. turns out I'm wrong! I need to be able to gather what is in the string from the first | to the last ", so from "1|2|3" I would want 2|3 ... can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) like this:

```
>>> string = '+CPBR: 1,"111",129,"0|2|XX"^M'
>>> import re
>>> re.search('\|([^|"]+)"',string).group(1)
'XX'
>>> string = '+CPBR: 1,"111",129,"0|2|9X"^M'
'9X'
>>> string = '+CPBR: 1,"111",129,"0|2|ABC"^M'
'ABC'
```

This will match everything between | and " which does not contain either character (|").

Comment: this is the exact code that i thought i wanted! do you know how I would get either |Y|Z or Y|Z from "X|Y|Z". the first divider is | and the last is " thanks!

Comment: Given the pattern "X|Y|Z", the regular expression '"([^|"]+)\|([^|"]+)\|([^|"]+)"' will given you three groups: group(1) will be X, group(2) will be Y and group(3) will be Z. You can then recombine the X, Y and Z strings as you require. If this was helpful, don't forget to accept the answer ;P

Answer (score 1):

```
In [2]: a=r'+CPBR: 1,"111",129,"0|2|XX"^M'

In [3]: b=r'+CPBR: 1,"111",129,"01|2|9X"^M'

In [4]: a.split('|')[-1][0:2]
Out[4]: 'XX'

In [5]: b.split('|')[-1][0:2]
Out[5]: '9X'
```